# How do I send available_apps in context to a view that is outside the admin panel in Django?

Tags: python, django

How can I get an application list like in get_app_list method in classy AdminSite?

I try to do it this way, but then I get an empty list.

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite

    def change_view(self, request):
        ...

        context = {
            ...
            'available_apps': AdminSite().get_app_list(request)
        }
        return render(request, 'parts/part_form.html', context=context)
```

I need this to display the admin side menu outside the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `AdminSite`, I'm not sure but that might be incorrect according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.get_app_list).

Does `AdminSite.get_app_list(request)` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.apps import apps

for app in apps.get_app_configs():
    print(app.verbose_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
from django.contrib import admin

app_list = admin.site.get_app_list(request)

for app in app_list:
    print("App name:", app['name'])
    print("App models:")
    for model in app['models']:
        print(f"  - {model['name']} ({model['object_name']})")
```